# Configure log4j 2 using xml

Tags: java, xml, logging, log4j2

I'd like to have log messages shown in three ways:
- on console
- on a single file log/logs/log.log file
- on a monthly changed file of the kind log/logs/log-201610.log

I wrote this configuration (using other questions here and several sources I can't find):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
        <File name="basic" fileName="log/log.log">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="%d{dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </File>
        <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="log/logs/app.log"
            filePattern="log/logs/log-%d{yyyyMM}.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>"%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %m%n"</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="ALL">
            <AppenderRef ref="console" />
        </Root>
        <Logger name="sistema" level="ALL" additivity="true">
            <AppenderRef ref="basic" />
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="sistemabis" level="ALL" additivity="true">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

It seems to work properly (doesn't give errors), but I get an empty file in log/logs/app.log . In my file dependencies.xml I have this:

```
    <dependency org="org.apache.logging.log4j"   name="log4j-api"           rev="2.5"    transitive="false"/>
    <dependency org="org.apache.logging.log4j"   name="log4j-core"          rev="2.5"    transitive="false"/>
```

but I am afraid I'm still missing something.
Most likely, one day I'll remove the logging on the single full file (so I need to be able to distinguish among appenders). No size bound is needed.
Where am I wrong?
EDIT: according to what I read in comments, I edited to show the situa

Comment: I'm not sure the syntax is correct for 'appender', shouldn't it be a 'File' or 'RollingFile' element here ?
You should have a look at the documentation : https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender

Comment: I added some extra material, due to your suggestions. But I'm still unable to make it work properly.

Comment: Strange, have you tried the exact example from log4j2 how-to ?
Which version of loj4j2 are you using ?

Comment: At the moment I'm using 1.2.17, but I can't find any real example of a log divided on monthly basis, and I'd like to find it asap because I'd like to test it when november begins.

Comment: Yeah, exactly, the syntax you are using is for Log4j2, but you are using log4j.
Try this : http://www.codejava.net/coding/configure-log4j-for-creating-daily-rolling-log-files

Comment: To be more specific, I have this in my dependencies:        <dependency org="log4j"                      name="log4j"               rev="1.2.17" transitive="false"/>
        <dependency org="org.apache.logging.log4j"   name="log4j-api"           rev="2.5"    transitive="false"/>
        <dependency org="org.apache.logging.log4j"   name="log4j-core"          rev="2.5"    transitive="false"/>

Comment: I think you can use only the 1.2.17 dependency, this was the old log4j, which used only one jar. The new log4j2 uses 3 jars, that's why you have the api and core, but this doesn't concern you as you are using the 1.2.17 version

Comment: What should I do if I wanted to pass to log4j2 as far as dependencies are concerned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to comments, I modified dependencies and replaced some lines in the configuration file:

```
<Pattern>%d{dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern>

    <Logger name="sistema" level="ALL" additivity="true"> <!-- name è il nome del pacchetto radice da cui prendere. -->
        <AppenderRef ref="basic" />
        <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
    </Logger>
```

It seems to work properly. On 1 November, I'll know more about this.